# Displaying two maps on top of each other using Gmap.NET

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm using Gmap.net. I can display one map as described in http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-beginners-tutorial-maps-markers-polygons-routes-updated-for-vs2015-and-gmap1-7.html.

However I need to display 2 maps one top of another. In ArcGIS I can do it easly, bu in Gmap.net I can not! Why I need 2 maps top of each other, because one map have some new tiles but not all the world, but older one has all the old tiles. I want to show 2 maps on top of each other so that old tiles are in back and new tiles are on top.

Please help, thank you.